How to allow a browser permission in NightWatch.js tests?
I'm using NightWatch.js to build e2e tests.
One of my tests requires to grant the Chrome browser's microphone permission.
When I run this test, I get a permission notification from the Chrome browser and I have to manually allow it. I would like to automate this.
Is there any way I can use NightWatch.js script to click allow button on this notification or set the microphone permission allowed in nightwatch.conf.js directly?


I added --use-fake-device-for-media-stream and --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream to nightwatch.conf.js and it worked.
This allowed the microphone permission in background during the test.
this is the modified nightwatch.conf.js.
module.exports = {
    src_folders: ["tests"], // replace with your test folder
    
    webdriver: {
      start_process: true,
      port: 4444,
      server_path: require('chromedriver').path,
      cli_args: []
    },
    
    test_settings: {
      default: {
        launch_url: 'https://nightwatchjs.org',
        desiredCapabilities : {
          browserName : 'chrome',
          'goog:chromeOptions' : {
            w3c: true,
            args: [
              ...
              '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
              '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'
              ...
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

